# Progress bar reference problem using Flask

Tags: python, flask, progress-bar

I'm attempting to make a progress bar update in a Flask Web App. The progress bar appears but is not updated when my code is run.

I'm building a fairly simple WebApp in Flask, scrapping data from a website (I got permission to do it) that has 100 labels *wine brands* These are sorted, I saved them and extracted them in a CSV file.

But before, let me show you what I would like to implement, which works fine, *app.py* and *progress_bar.html* the aim is to get a progress bar to update, but in my current code (will it be at the button)

The following app.py works fine (this is what I am using as a reference)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('progress_bar.html')

def run_counter():
    counter = 0
    while counter <= 100:
        time.sleep(1)  
        counter += 1
        app.counter = counter  
        print("Counter value:", counter)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_counter)
    counter_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> progress_bar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center">Progress Bar</h1>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function updateProgressBar(percentage) {
            const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
            progressBar.style.width = percentage + '%';
            progressBar.innerText = percentage + '%';
        }

        function runCounter() {
            let counter = 0;
            const interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (counter >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                }
                counter += 1;
                updateProgressBar(counter);
            }, 100); // Adjust the interval as needed
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runCounter);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I stated above the following code, works without any problem: I got the progress bar updated.

*My issue is when I try to 'adapt' this logic into my code.

> What I would like

Display 1% (and fill the bar accordingly) when the first *Wine Label* is extracted, 2% when the Second *Wine Label* is extracted, and so on...

> app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv
import subprocess
import json
import random

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')


# Route to render the index.html template
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', posts=POSTS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In here, *main.py*, scrape through each WineBrand (I got authorization to do it) and save it in a file, it is possible to use the counter as % to get a progress bar to update, as a reference?

I tried to implement it, but when I run my code the progress bar appears but does not update. So instead of writing all my attempts, I am not asking you to write the code, but maybe some hint? What is the best way to 'call'  *counter* from my main.py and use it to build the progress /percentage bar? I want both, my *main.py* and the bar filling/getting updated  at the same time

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')

# URL 
url = "https://www.example.com/wines"

# Open the URL in the browser
driver.get(url)


wine_brands = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='wine-brand']")

# CSV
csv_filename = "wine_brands_selenium.csv"
csv_file = open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["Brand Name"])


counter = 1
while counter <= len(wine_brands):
    wine_brand = wine_brands[counter - 1]
    brand_name = wine_brand.text
    csv_writer.writerow([brand_name])
    print(f"{counter}. {brand_name}")
    counter += 1


driver.quit()
csv_file.close()

print("Scraping completed. Data saved to", csv_filename)
```